# Python Numpy Array Modification

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a plot y vs x.
Based on some boundary conditions, I have obtained a list of x-values and corresponding y-values

```
x = [2, 4, 8, 11, 18, 24, 31]
```

the corresponding y-values are

```
y = [180, 139, 144, 90, 81, 109, 153]
```

the output is an array that returns twice the value of x
output = `[4, 8, 16, 22, 36, 48, 62]`

My task is to limit the final output array to 5 values maximum. These values should correspond to the 5 highest values in the array y.

So, I should get

```
output = [4, 8, 16, 48, 62]
```

Also, different data sets will give different no. of x and y values. So, if the original output array has less than or equal to 5 values, it should be printed as it is.

I am trying to find a way to do this with a couple of lines of code.

Comment: So, have you done this already with more than the couple of lines you're aiming for (which would be a refactoring issue), or are you having problems implementing this at all? What have you attempted so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem basically comes down to the question on how to obtain n highest values of an array. You will need the `argsort()` for this.

```
if len(y) > 4:
    n_highest = 5
else:
    n_highest = len(y)

y_highest = y.argsort()[-n_highest:][::-1] # this gives you the indices of the five highest values of y

x_out = x[y_highest] * 2
```

If you don't want `x_out` to be sorted, but rather reflect the original sorting, you'd have to iterate through eatch item, asking if its index is found in `y_highest`:

```
x_out = [x[i]*2 for i in range(len(x)) if i in y_highest]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reorder the array with

```
array = sorted(array)
```

After that you just need to take the 5 first terms:

```
output = array[0:4]
```

Remember that we need to write 4 instead of 5 because on Python array's dimension starts ar 0. You can do this with less code:

```
output = sorted(array)[0:4]
```

Comment: Only problem is, rahul needs the indices of the n highest values of y and extract those from x. Hence I suggest `argsort` instead of `sorted`.